# What is the meaning of the phrase "Power series expansion about $x = 0$"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I recently came across a problem that contained a phrase stating

> Power series expansion about $x = 0$ of $(1 + x)^a$

What do "about $x = 0$" and "of $(1 + x)^a$" mean ?

Is it same as "at $x = 0$"?

If anybody could help it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "Power series expansion about $x = 0$" means the same as "Power series expansion at $x = 0$". I think "about" is a bit more accurate, since you're using derivatives which by definition care about what the function looks like not just at $x = 0$ but also in the immediate vicinity.

"of $(1+x)^a$" means that that's the function whose power series expansion you are asked to find.

Answer (score 0):

It means write $$(1+x)^a = \sum_{i} c_i(x-b)^i$$

It is referring to the case when $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "a power series expansion about $x=\lambda$" means an infinite series in the form of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-\lambda)^n$. So, a power series expansion about $x=0$ means an infinite series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), the idea behind it is to write the function $(1 + x)^a$ as an (possibly) infinite sum of terms of them $c_k (x - x_0)^k$, $k=0,1,\cdots$ and in your case $x_0 = 0$ (that's the meaning of "around $x_0 = 0$")

$$
(1 + x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k
$$

The coefficients $c_k$ are calculated with the derivatives of the function

$$
c_k = \frac{1}{k!}\left.\frac{{\rm d}^k}{{\rm d}x^k}(1 + x)^a\right|_{x=x_0=0}
$$

The idea is that the more terms you include in this sum, the closer it gets to the actual function

[image]

You can see from this figure that the approximation becomes increasingly better *around $x=0$* with the number of terms added to the sum